# Trigger Element Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

### [JSFiddle Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MrTIMarshall2512/z8ay1b7L/2/)

### Script Explanation

My script is to sort and/or filter a mailbox whereas you can select one of each options and the sort option upon clicking, if it's active it'll switch the icon indicating going from A-Z to Z-A and visa-versa.

The filter option changes the button text and upon clicking on the button it'll animate the button width to the drop down width and then slide down the drop down. Upon clicking again, it'll reverse the process, checking to see if the text has been changed to adjust for the width.

### What I Wish To Implement

Upon clicking one of the options apart from the `.Active` filter/view options, I wish to trigger the click event to reverse the show progress. I have tried to trigger this click hover with using `e.target`, I'm not sure how to trigger this correctly as my attempts have been doing nothing.

Comment: Add relevant code  __it in the question itself.__

Comment: @Satpal actually this code is fully working, I'm asking how can I trigger the click event properly to reverse the process.

Comment: @Satpal Please try the fiddle again

Comment: @TimMarshall, _I wish to trigger the click event to reverse the show progress_ - do you want to hide the menu?

Comment: @Maximus Click on the button then click on it again to hide. This is what I wish to happen upon clicking any of the `.Sort` options active or not, or any of the `.Filter` / `.View` which are not active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `trigger` event seems to be working fine, you're only triggering it on the wrong element. This seems to be working:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger("click");
```

I've updated the [plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/z8ay1b7L/3/)

Comment: I've got quite a big swelling come up in my mouth making programming much harder to concentrate on. It appears that I had the answer but was triggering a click on the wrong element!

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the click this way.

```
if ($(e.target).closest('.Sort').length) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('Active')) {
    $(e.target).parent().find('i').toggleClass("fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-up");
  } else {
    $('.dropdown-menu .Sort').find('.Active').removeClass('Active');
    $('.dropdown-menu .Sort').find('i').remove();
    $(e.target).addClass('Active');
    $(e.target).prepend('<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> ');
  }

  //Here.
  //Ideally add another unique class to the main dropdown button and use that instead, otherwise you will have problems when there are multiple elements with dropdown-toggle class.
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click();
}
```